# Multiple JOIN Query - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, join

The table structure described is just for guidance. The column names are different compared to that of the DB.

I have a rather an unusual DB. I have agent table (**Agents**) with following structure.

```
A_ID(PK)|    AgentName    |    Team
------------------------------------
1       |    Abi          |    New
2       |    Carl         |    New
3       |    James        |    New
```

I have two other tables that has several fields but the ones in question have fields like..

Table: **Transactions**

```
ID(PK)  |    manyColumns  |    Agent_ID    |    OUTCOME
--------------------------------------------------------
96      |    ...          |    1           |    9          
98      |    ....         |    2           |    8       
99      |    .....        |    3           |    1
```

Table: **RAWDATA**

```
ID(PK)  |    manyColumns  |    Agent_ID    |    BANK_OUTCOME
-------------------------------------------------------------
1234    |    ...          |    1           |    3
1114    |    ....         |    2           |    333
1745    |    .....        |    3           |    123
```

I have a log table with the details of the staff working hours..

Table: **AGENT_ATTENDANCE**

```
ATT_ID  |    Hours Worked |    Agent_ID_FK 
-------------------------------------------
96      |    7.5          |    1            
98      |    7.5          |    2             
99      |    7.5          |    3
```

I also have a details of staff pay, hours contracted.

Table: **AGENT_DETAILS**

```
DT_ID   |    Hours WK      |    Pay    |    Agent_ID_FK 
-------------------------------------------------------
96      |    37.5          |    15600  |    1            
98      |    37.5          |    15600  |    2             
99      |    37.5          |    15600  |    3
```

I have created separate queries but I want to display as one.. As the calculation depend on each other.. I am not sure how to do it.. The following are separate Queries.. How can I JOIN them as one??

**Query - 1:**

```
PARAMETERS [EnterStartDate:] DateTime, [EnterEndDate:] DateTime;

SELECT Agents.[Agent Name], 
Sum(IIf((([TRANSACTIONS].[BankOutcome]=3) Or ([TRANSACTIONS].[BankOutcome]=333)),1,0)) AS PositiveOutcome, 
Count(RAWDATA.Outcome) AS TotalRecordsUsed

FROM (RAWDATA LEFT JOIN Agents ON RAWDATA.[AGENT_ID] = Agents.A_ID) LEFT JOIN
TRANSACTIONS ON RAWDATA.ID = TRANSACTIONS.RAW_ID 

WHERE (((RAWDATA.DialedDate) Between [EnterStartDate:] And [EnterEndDate:]))

GROUP BY Agents.[Agent Name], RAWDATA.AGENT_ID

HAVING (((RAWDATA.AGENT_ID) Is Not Null));
```

**Query - 2:**

```
PARAMETERS [EnterStartDate:] DateTime, [EnterEndDate:] DateTime;

SELECT Agents.[Agent Name], AGENT_DETAILS.WK_TARGET_HOURS,
Sum(AGENT_ATTENDENCE.HoursWorked_Day) AS [Actual Hours Worked], 
[WK_TARGET_HOURS]-[Actual Hours Worked] AS [Hours Lost], AGENT_DETAILS.SALARY, 
Round([SALARY]/252/([WK_TARGET_HOURS]/5),2) AS [Hourly Rate], [Hourly Rate]*[Actual Hours Worked] AS [Staff Cost]

FROM (Agents INNER JOIN AGENT_DETAILS ON Agents.A_ID = AGENT_DETAILS.AGENT_ID_fk)
INNER JOIN AGENT_ATTENDENCE ON Agents.A_ID = AGENT_ATTENDENCE.AGENT_ID_fk

WHERE (((AGENT_ATTENDENCE.WorK_Date) Between [EnterStartDate:] And [EnterEndDate:]))

GROUP BY Agents.[Agent Name], AGENT_DETAILS.WK_TARGET_HOURS, AGENT_DETAILS.SALARY, 
Agents.Active, Agents.Team

HAVING (((Agents.Active)=True) AND ((Agents.Team)<>"Manager" And (Agents.Team)<>"Cust. Ser."));
```

Could attach the file if I could but I do not know how to.

Comment: "JOIN them as one" is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as tabular initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get into your code, but roughly you have 3 choices:

- If both queries have the same fields (not your case apparently) you can use a UNION query to have the data of both queries in 1 dataset.
- Otherwise, you can use query1 as the source of query2
- Finally you can build query1 and query2, then use a third query to JOIN the first 2

Comment: Hello @iDevlop.. I understand what you mean, but the problem is that Query 1 and Query 2 have a common table agents which they need to get the Agent ID from, that is the reason I was thinking if there might be a better way of doing it.. but I will give it a try and let you know how option 3 goes on for me..

Comment: Thank you, that is what I needed,, it works perfect.. just some more tweeks and I think I will be good to go..